# Nyquist Frequency Restriction - How to only mix harmonics that are below the Nyqvist Limit

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing, synthesis

I am using the getSampleRate() helper function to work out the Nyquist limit and assign it to a temporary local variable.

I must now update the part of the class that mixes the harmonics together so that only harmonics with frequencies below the Nyquist limit are included in the mix. Supposedly getFrequency() will find out what frequency it's set to, but after that I'm still not sure how to only include those frequencies. An if statement perhaps.

```
class SawWave
{
public:
void reset()
{

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_HARMONICS; i++)
    {
        harmonic[i].reset();

    }
}

void setFrequency(float frequency){

    for(int i=0; i < MAX_HARMONICS; i++)
    {
        harmonic[i].setFrequency(frequency * (i + 1));
    }
}

float tick()
{
    float nyquist = getSampleRate() * 0.5;   
    float sum = 0;
    int count;


    for (count = 0; count < MAX_HARMONICS; count++)
    {
        sum += (harmonic[count].tick()) * 1 / (count + 1);
    }
    return sum;
}

protected:

Sine harmonic[MAX_HARMONICS];
};
```

Comment: You want a low-pass filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned that you have access to the individual harmonic's frequencies with `Sine::getFrequency()`, you simply need to exclude them from the generated signal accumulated in `sum`:

```
for (count = 0; count < MAX_HARMONICS; count++)
{
    if (harmonic[count].getFrequency() < nyquist)
    {
        sum += (harmonic[count].tick()) * 1 / (count + 1);
    }
}
```

Note that you could also stop generating further harmonics as soon as you find one that is not less than `nyquist` since you are storing the harmonics in order of increasing frequency:

```
for (count = 0; count < MAX_HARMONICS; count++)
{
    if (harmonic[count].getFrequency() < nyquist)
    {
        sum += (harmonic[count].tick()) * 1 / (count + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```